# Focus DecimalUpDowns depending on boolean property in view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I would like to focus multiple `DecimalUpDown`s based on a boolean property on the`ViewModel`

Below is the XAML. For example, if I bind `IsFocused` on `DecimalUpDown` to a property on my view model it does not work. I know it is possible via creating a behavior, but I don't understand how to do that, yet.

```
//This is DecimalUpDown1 
<DecimalUpDown IsFocused={Binding IsDUD1Invalid} />

//This is DecimalUpDown2
<DecimalUpDown IsFocused={Binding IsDUD2Invalid} />
```

```
private bool _isDUD1Invalid = false;
public bool IsDUD1Invalid
{
    get { return _isDUD1Invalid; }
    set
    {
        _isDUD1Invalid = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsDUD1Invalid)));
    }
}

private bool _isDUD2Invalid = false;
public bool IsDUD2Invalid
{
    get { return _isDUD2Invalid; }
    set
    {
        _isDUD2Invalid = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsDUD2Invalid)));
    }
}

private void SampleCommand1()
{
    //Focus DecimalUpDown1
    IsDUD1Invalid = true;
}

private void SampleCommand2()
{
    //Focus DecimalUpDown1
    IsDUD2Invalid = true;
}
```

Of course, it could focus only one `DecimalUpDown` at a time. I would like to avoid specific external triggers from the view to set the focus like clicking a button. I want it to be triggered by any method that changes the value of the boolean property. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`IsFocused`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isfocused?view=netcore-3.1) property is *read-only*, so you cannot bind it that way. However, you can create an attached property to give keyboard focus to a UI element when a condition is `True`.

```
public static class ConditionalFocusProperties
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ConditionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Condition", typeof(bool), typeof(ConditionalFocusProperties), new PropertyMetadata(OnConditionChanged));

   public static bool GetCondition(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(ConditionProperty);
   }

   public static void SetCondition(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(ConditionProperty, value);
   }

   private static void OnConditionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!(d is UIElement uiElement))
         return;

      if ((bool) e.NewValue)
         Keyboard.Focus(uiElement);
      // Uncomment, if you want to remove the focus when "Condition" turns "false".
      /*
      else if (uiElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
         Keyboard.ClearFocus();
      */
   }
}
```

You can attach and bind the property in XAML like this for e.g. `IsDUD1Invalid`.

```
<DecimalUpDown local:ConditionalFocusProperties.Condition="{Binding IsDUD1Invalid}"/>
```

Comment: Great this works like a charm and works with other UI Elements. Thank you very much.